# Call Procedure with Ref cursor inside another procedure

Tags: php, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

I have 2 Procedures,

```
-- Procedure 1 on another server (db link)
PROCEDURE GET_TRANSACTIONS
(
    I_FROM_DT           VARCHAR2,
    I_TO_DT             VARCHAR2,
    I_ACC_NO            number,
    I_ACC_SUB_NO        number,
    I_CURR_NO           number,
    O_DATACUR   OUT     SYS_REFCURSOR
) AS
BEGIN
  open O_DATACUR  for select * from xtable where ...(where cluase) ...;
END;



-- Procedure 2
PROCEDURE GET_TRANSACTIONS
(
    I_FROM_DT           VARCHAR2,
    I_TO_DT             VARCHAR2,
    I_ACC_NO            number,
    I_ACC_SUB_NO        number,
    I_CURR_NO           number,
    O_DATACUR   OUT     SYS_REFCURSOR
) AS
BEGIN

   XPKG.GET_TRANSACTIONS@XDBLINK_DB
    (
      I_FROM_DT, I_TO_DT, I_ACC_NO, I_ACC_SUB_NO,I_CURR_NO,  O_DATACUR
    );
END;
```

Now in PHP I will call GET_TRANSACTIONS (Procedure 2) .. 
I am trying to get the data from DataRec but there is no data returned on  the other hand .. if i called GET_TRANSACTIONS (Procedure 2) directly... it will return data ..

Any solution Please?
Note, I am working on Oracle 11g

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Hello i tried to repoduce the same scenario without using DB LINK and i am able to see that the Proc 2 returns data. There might be some issue with data with the table where you are using DB Link to fetch the data. Hope below snippet helps you.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_TRANSACTIONS(
    I_FROM_DT    VARCHAR2,
    I_TO_DT      VARCHAR2,
    I_ACC_NO     NUMBER,
    I_ACC_SUB_NO NUMBER,
    I_CURR_NO    NUMBER,
    O_DATACUR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR )
AS
BEGIN
  OPEN O_DATACUR FOR SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL < 5;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_TRANSACTIONS_1(
    I_FROM_DT    VARCHAR2,
    I_TO_DT      VARCHAR2,
    I_ACC_NO     NUMBER,
    I_ACC_SUB_NO NUMBER,
    I_CURR_NO    NUMBER,
    O_DATACUR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR )
AS
BEGIN
  GET_TRANSACTIONS ( I_FROM_DT, I_TO_DT, I_ACC_NO, I_ACC_SUB_NO,I_CURR_NO, O_DATACUR );
END;

--Check the output----------

var o_cur refcursor;
EXEC GET_TRANSACTIONS_1('1','1',1,1,1,:o_cur);
PRINT O_CUR;


LEVEL                                   
--------------------------------------- 
1                                       
2                                       
3                                       
4
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to test it locally I created 2 local procedures as u did .. it worked fine .. but the problem is still exists for the db link ..
Means .. if I called the procedure from db link ... it will return empty cursor